# Direction of Estimate coefficient in a Log Regression

Tags: r, statistics, logistic-regression, mixed-models

I'm analysing ordinal logistic regression and I'm wondering, how to know which direction the estimate coefficient has? My Variables are just 0, 1 for Women, Men and 0,1,2,4 for different postures. So my question is, how do I know, if the estimate describes the change from 0 to 1 or the change from 1 to 0, talking about gender?

The output added a 1 to PicSex, is it a sign, that this one has a 1->0 direction? See the code for that.

Thank you for any help

```
Cumulative Link Mixed Model fitted with the Laplace approximation

formula: Int ~ PicSex + Posture + (1 | PicID)
data:    x

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 PicID  (Intercept) 0.0541   0.2326  
Number of groups:  PicID 16 

Coefficients:
        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
PicSex1   0.3743     0.1833   2.042   0.0411 *  
Posture  -1.1232     0.1866  -6.018 1.77e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


P.S.
Thank you here are my head results (I relabeled PicSex to Sex)

> head(Posture)
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1
Levels: 0 1
> head(Sex)
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0
Levels: 0 1

So the level order is the same, but on Sex it still added  a 1 but on posture not. Still very confused about the directions.
```

Comment: Have you got the code you used to get this formula e.g. `glm(...)` or equivalent? It should be clear if you know your link function but an easy way to test it is to predict with the model object with the `predict` function on new values of posture, and observe whether the prediction increases or decreases

Comment: If I understand correctly, PicSex1 is a fixed effect of sex, and is categorical. Thus the overall intercept for your model is whichever sex level R recognizes as the first one (so if you coded sex as F or M, F would be the reference because it is first in alphabet). The RE of PicID is centered at "0," but really it's the variance around the intercept terms after you fit the intercepts for sex. I would, as a sanity check, just do `levels(PicSex)`, although the suggestion to use the `predict` function is a great one too.

Comment: I used following code: "var.with.red <- clmm(Int ~ Sex + Posture+ (1|PicID), data = x)  " from package control - How do I use the term predict in this case? Many thanks @Michael and Jonny Phelps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sex has two levels,0 or 1. So PicSex1 means the effect of PicSex being 1 compared to PicSex being 0. I show an example below using the wine dataset:

```
library(ordinal)
DATA = wine
> head(DATA$temp)
[1] cold cold cold cold warm warm
Levels: cold warm
```

Here cold comes first in Levels, so it is set as the reference in any linear models.First we verify the effect of cold vs warm

```
do.call(cbind,tapply(DATA$rating,DATA$temp,table))
#warm has a higher average rating
```

Fit the model

```
# we fit the a model, temp is fixed effect
summary(clmm(rating ~ temp + contact+(1|judge), data = DATA))
Cumulative Link Mixed Model fitted with the Laplace approximation

formula: rating ~ temp + contact + (1 | judge)
data:    DATA

 link  threshold nobs logLik AIC    niter    max.grad cond.H 
 logit flexible  72   -81.57 177.13 332(999) 1.03e-05 2.8e+01

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 judge  (Intercept) 1.279    1.131   
Number of groups:  judge 9 

Coefficients:
           Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
tempwarm     3.0630     0.5954   5.145 2.68e-07 ***
contactyes   1.8349     0.5125   3.580 0.000344 ***
```

Here we see warm being attached to "temp" and as we know, it has a positive coefficient because the rating is better in warm, compared to cold (the reference).

So if you set another group as the reference, you will see another name attached, and the coefficient is reversed (-3.. compared to +3.. in previous example)

```
# we set warm as reference now
DATA$temp = relevel(DATA$temp,ref="warm")

summary(clmm(rating ~ temp + contact+(1|judge), data = DATA))
Cumulative Link Mixed Model fitted with the Laplace approximation

formula: rating ~ temp + contact + (1 | judge)
data:    DATA

 link  threshold nobs logLik AIC    niter    max.grad cond.H 
 logit flexible  72   -81.57 177.13 269(810) 1.14e-04 1.8e+01

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 judge  (Intercept) 1.28     1.131   
Number of groups:  judge 9 

Coefficients:
           Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
tempcold    -3.0630     0.5954  -5.145 2.68e-07 ***
contactyes   1.8349     0.5125   3.580 0.000344 ***
```

So always check what is the reference before you fit the model

Comment: Thank you here are my head results (I relabeled PicSex to Sex)

> head(Posture)
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1
Levels: 0 1
> head(Sex)
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0
Levels: 0 1

So the level order is the same, but on Sex it still added  a 1 but on posture not.

Comment: weird, if you use my example, you can see the factors. I think something is strange with your data.

Comment: I transformed the data as factors like Sex = factor(x$PicSex) . Can it be a source of error?

Comment: if x$PicSex was numeric it should be fine. Hey Felix, I really cannot tell without a reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you, I got the solution.: Posture was too long, R added open or closed after I shortened Var name Posture to Pos. @StupidWolf

Comment: Oh.. ok so it's only in the print then? If you do coefficients(summary(..))) I guess it should be ok